# Why this loop is showing the same response in angular click event?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dynamic, chat

I am trying to log the data of user according to user tab on which we have clicked. But the issue is that it is showing same one data not others.

[image]

Like above if I click on Sara it shows me Sara, but when I click on Edita it shows still Sara.
Kindly someone help how to achieve the data according to user tab clicked

ts file

```
response: Array<any> = [];

getUsers(){
    this.http.get('https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/user', {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('app-id', '63a1a3fdf4c5089b8564caef'),
      params: new HttpParams().set('limit', '50')
    }).subscribe(data => {
      
      this.response.push(data);

    }), ((error: object) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

 showChat(){
    for(let i=0; i<this.response.length; i++){
      console.log(this.response[0].data[i])
    }
  }
```

html file

```
<div class="user-bottom">
        <div class="all-users" *ngFor="let array of response" (click)="showChat()" >
            <div class="nested-items" *ngFor="let data of array.data">
                <h4>{{data.firstName}}</h4>&nbsp;
                <img src="{{data.picture}}" alt="profile">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not clear why do you need the `response` array, but if you want to loop through `data` that should be `let i=0; i<this.response[0].data.length; i++`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here.

`response` only contains one element, so your `for` loop in `showChat()` only loops once.

Your click listener is on the parent element, not each separate child element.

With your current setup, you'd want a template along the lines of:

```html
<div class="user-bottom">
  <div class="all-users" *ngFor="let array of response">
    <div class="nested-items" *ngFor="let data of array.data; let i = index;" (click)="showChat(i)">
      <h4>{{data.firstName}}</h4>&nbsp;
      <img src="{{data.picture}}" alt="profile">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And your method would change to something like:

```js
showChat(i: number) {
  console.log(this.response[0][i]);
}
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes you are right. I was doing the wrong way. 
```
console.log(this.response[0].data[i])
```
solves the problem along with correction in template!